# "zipalign.exe" exited with code 1. (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, zipalign

After update my vs2017 to 16.6.5, and update google sdk-build-tools to 27.0.3, my project got a problem with debugging for my tablet. My project type is xamarin.android, I check it for xamarin.forms but debugging for  my (not emulator) tablet is woks! Also before this update i don't have any problem with debugging.
Here is my project output in diagnostic mode:

```
3>Done executing task "Delete".
3>Using "AndroidZipAlign" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".
3>Task "AndroidZipAlign"
3>Task Parameter:Source=F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush.apk
3>Task Parameter:DestinationDirectory=bin\Debug\
3>Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3
3>AndroidZipAlign Task
3>  Alignment: 4
3>  Source: F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush.apk
3>  DestinationDirectory: bin\Debug\
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.aminsystem.forush-Signed.apk" 
3>Done executing task "AndroidZipAlign".
3>Task "AndroidZipAlign"
3>Task Parameter:Source=F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush-armeabi-v7a.apk
3>Task Parameter:DestinationDirectory=bin\Debug\
3>Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3
3>AndroidZipAlign Task
3>  Alignment: 4
3>  Source: F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush-armeabi-v7a.apk
3>  DestinationDirectory: bin\Debug\
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "F:\Projects\Amin\AminApp\AminApp\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.aminsystem.forush-armeabi-v7a.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.aminsystem.forush-armeabi-v7a-Signed.apk" 
3>Output file 'bin\Debug\\com.aminsystem.forush-armeabi-v7a-Signed.apk' exists
3>"zipalign.exe" exited with code 1.
3>Done executing task "AndroidZipAlign" -- FAILED.
3>Done building target "_Sign" in project "AminApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
3>Done building project "AminApp.csproj" -- FAILED.
3>Build FAILED.
3>
3>Deploy failed on Samsung SM-T585
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

As you see my project compiled successfully!

I also tried copy zipalign.exe from Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3 to Android\android-sdk\tools, but it not works.

Comment: Try [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/) article and configure property as per given instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the Debug option to X86!
Thanks to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/deployment-error-with-xamarin-android-application

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `zipalign.exe` was being blocked by the Windows Virus & Threat protection and once I allowed it, it started working fine.